# How to use attributes for accessing private data in hyperledger fabric v1.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there any way to leverage Private Data functionality in hyperledger fabric using certificate attributes?

```
[
 {
    "name": "collectionMarbles",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":1000000
 },
 {
    "name": "collectionMarblePrivateDetails",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":3
 }
]
```

According to documentations we can use OrgName.member to specifiy nodes that can access data. Is there any workaround in chaincode or any other method.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Fabric provides 'cid' package. You can check its usage in [fabric-samples - abac.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/chaincode/abac/go/abac.go)

With it, you can do following,

- Check if client has a specific attribute

  - if yes, let client read or modify a private data
  - if no, return error with permission violation

Comment: I am familiar with cid package. but how can I access private data if the certificate has the required attributes but is not allowed to read the private data? e.g in above collection what if a certificate from Org2 have the required attributes and want to access private data from `collectionMarblePrivateDetails` collection.